# Resolver problema com o Docker para Windows

Tags: windows, docker, máquina-virtual

Não estou conseguindo iniciar o Docker no Windows, já refiz o processo de instalação mais o erro informado é o mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que a virtualização esta ativa na minha estação de trabalho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a configuração básica da minha estação de trabalho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de informações de como posso estar resolvendo esse problema.

Comment: A virtualização está ativada na BIOS?

Comment: Sim esta, verifiquei também, isso que é estranho, esta ativada na BIOS, esta ativa no Sistema Operacional também, complementando as informações estou utilizando o sistema operacional Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Hyper-V tá ativo e rodando normal?

Comment: Verifica se o Hyper-V está ativado, se tiver e mesmo assim estiver dando erro, tenta desativar e reativar ele de novo

Comment: Desativei na BIOS e reativei a Virtualização, porém não resolveu o problema, também desinstalei e reinstalei o Docker, mas não tive sucesso em fazer o mesmo funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar da opção estar disponível no BIOS, este processador não possui tecnologia de virtualização (necessário para rodar o docker no Windows).
([Link 1](https://communities.intel.com/thread/6259))
([Link 2](https://ark.intel.com/products/36503/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7500-3M-Cache-2_93-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB#specs))
([Link 3](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/300341-28-core-e7500-virtualization-technology))

**Mas não se preocupe.**
Há outras formas de usar o Docker sem que você precise trocar o seu Sistema Operacional.
Pode instalar o VirtualBox e usar uma Máquina Virtual com qualquer Linux Server (para economizar memória) ou o projeto Boot2Docker.
Comento mais sobre isso [neste post do meu blog](https://www.seniocaires.com.br/blog/post/docker-windows.html).